# Alternative (args...) token for the CL compiler

Tags: c

What is the alternative token (args...) for the CL compiler?

```
#define DECLARE_C_ARRAY(__type, __name, __page, __args...) \
enum { __name##_page_size = __page }; \
typedef __type __name##_element_t; \
typedef C_ARRAY_SIZE_TYPE __name##_count_t; \
typedef struct __name##_t {\
    volatile __name##_count_t count;\
    volatile __name##_count_t size;\
    __name##_element_t * e;\
    __args ;\
} __name##_t, *__name##_p;
```

[Example for the GCC compiler](http://rextester.com/PXXSBG91440)

Comment: When you say "The CL compiler" do you mean "The Microsoft Visual C++ compiler for C"?  What is the problem  you are having?

Comment: What's the CL compiler?

Comment: Yes, I mean `MS Visual C` compiler. 
I added a reference to a working example for the GCC compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to [Variadic macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html)

> Variadic macros are a new feature in C99. GNU CPP has supported them
>   for a long time, but only with a named variable argument (‘args...’,
>   not ‘...’ and **__VA_ARGS__**). If you are concerned with portability to
>   previous versions of GCC, you should use only named variable
>   arguments. On the other hand, if you are concerned with portability to
>   other conforming implementations of C99, you should use only
>   **__VA_ARGS__**.

Change

```
#define DECLARE_C_ARRAY(__type, __name, __page, __args...) \
```

to

```
#define DECLARE_C_ARRAY(__type, __name, __page, ...) \
```

and

```
__args ;\
```

to

```
__VA_ARGS__;\
```

> Unfortunately, this method does not work, if we exclude the args

In this case, remove the semicolon `__VA_ARGS__\` (but pass-it when args is used).

An example: http://rextester.com/GYVS61567

Comment: Unfortunately, this method does not work, if we exclude the `args` parameter. http://rextester.com/OTMQ48451

Comment: Well, if this is the only solution, it can be stated that the VC is clearly inferior to the compiler GCC. Thank you